# How to dynamically add pair of columns

Tags: r, sum, programming-languages

I have a dataframe with columns like this:
Income | Wt | Ht | Growth_Income | Growth_Wt | Growth_Ht.

Each column has 300 rows of numeric values. I would like to find a way how to add the columns that look the same (e.g. Income and Growth_Income). I would also like to find a way how to populate the dataframe so that i do the summation five times and each iteration is based on the previous output.

Sorry, im quite new with R and I havent thought of any way how to write the code yet. In excel, it would be easy dragging the formula but i need to code it in r because otherwise my program wont work. I hope someone could help me out here :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the patterns are as showed in the example, we  remove the substring prefix from the column names, use that to `split` the dataset into a `list` of `data.frame`s and loop through the `list` to get the `rowSums`

```
nm1 <- sub(".*_", "", names(df1))
sapply(split.default(df1, nm1), rowSums)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine. But now I have a new problem. I realized i need to do this three times. So for example, I need to add all the "Growth_" values to the sum (output) of the first iteration. It would make sense if i don't merge "Income | Wt | Ht |" and "Growth_Income | Growth_Wt | Growth_Ht" so I could call on the latter for the second iteration. My next question is how do I add columns with the same name (I will change "Growwth_Income to Income" from different dataframes (dynamically)?

Comment: I used: overlap = intersect(names(dfrm1), names(dfrm2))
dfrm1[overlap] = dfrm1[overlap] + dfrm2[overlap], but i dont know how to add them and still keep the id numbers attached in each row. Hope you could help me out again on this thanks